# Could I use the brand name 'Imodium' as a title for a short story?

Tags: fan-fiction

Good afternoon.  Could I use the brand name 'Imodium' as a title for my short story?

Comment: Probably not but there are some weird work arounds.

Answer (score 3):

Imodium is trademarked, so the company could send a cease and desist letter as a way to protect their protect their trademark -- that's part of the obligation of maintaining the trademark.

I've seen several posts about this very question, but very few by lawyers except for this post http://www.rightsofwriters.com/2010/12/can-i-mention-brand-name-products-in-my.html

Comment: This seems true, until I look at my bookshelf: *Prozac Nation*

Comment: @AugustCanaille is this a book about the prozac medicine and it's effect on the country? In which cause this may have been allowed by the company who did prozac.

Comment: [is prozac a trademark](https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/is-prozac-a-trademark--1903379.html)